# Android moves EditText's content to the next line automatically while typing

Tags: android

I need my EditText component to move the text to the next line when it reaches the end of the row.

And does anyone know how to prevent EditText from expanding vertically when it's filled with text?
Instead EditText should scroll vertically.
Is there a way to make it without fixing the size of EditText?

I searched the Web for relevant information but haven't found the answers.

Answer (score 17):

Put this in XML:

Use maxHeight for EditText expand vertically problem and android:inputType="textMultiLine" for shifting text to next line.

```
               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="140dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                >
               </EditText>
```

Comment: It doesn't work on some devices, is there any workaround

Answer (score 2):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

        android:minLines="10"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences">
        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following changes in your code.

in xml:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:lines="5"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:maxLines="6"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

or programmatically

```
 editText.apply {
      gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START
      setLines(5)
      minLines = 5
      maxLines = 6
      isSingleLine = false
}
```

I hope this will work.